# Microsoft Outlook Email not working with Manage Apps anymore

Tags: php, yii

We have had Microsoft Outlook email configure in our X2CRM previously. Since, the Microsoft has updated their Exchange and disable the Basic Authentication, we are left without any email integration with the CRM.

Do you have any idea of a fix for this or when it will be updated by the X2CRM?

I have tried the Manage Apps section from the CRM. Though, it does not recognize my email credentials anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest versions of X2CRM have already resolved this issue. In the latest version (currently `8.5`) that I am using, there is a new drop down option with text `Outlook Email Account with Oauth2` which is the OAuth2 integration with Microsoft. You can choose this option and proceed.

On the next screen, you can simply input your information and it will open the Microsoft authorization window and ask you to proceed. You just need to verify the permissions being granted and proceed to link your Microsoft account in X2CRM.

> You might also need to verify with your Administrator to ensure
> that Outlook Integration is updated and enabled for your email
> address.

Comment: Thank you. It works in the latest version! One more thing that I have seen is that it is only made available recently but there was no notification from the X2CRM team that it is available. What a pity!

Comment: Yes, I also found this out in a premium version of x2crm where there was a tutorial video linked as documentation for this new integration. You can find this video on Youtube as well. Other than this, their opensource support is very limited.